# Change to defayl map-image dont work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My code does not work I don't know why change the inactive images replace whit a default pictures and the code dont work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#map_image').error(function() {
                var $img = $(this);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $img.attr('src', '<?=base_url('assets/images/mapnotfound.png');?>' + '?' + Math.random());
                }, 1000);
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

View code is:

```
'.img(array('src'=>$this->settings->map_image($server->game, $server->currentmap),'id'=>'map_image','width'=>'120px','height'=>'120px')).'
```

Help me please to fix this plroblems.

Thanks

Comment: Your code under view code has single quotes inside single quotes. They have to be escaped.

Comment: Can you help me with the rectification of the code?

Comment: i'm not exactly sure what that line is doing, why does it start and end with fullstops? and it appears to be a string but it's not assigned to anything.

Comment: That line takes data about game servers.

See the model

Comment: `<?php 
        $servers = $this->settings->getLastVipServers();
        if($servers != 0){
         foreach($servers as $server){
          echo '
          <div class="col-md-12 " style="border:1px solid powderblue;">
          <div class="slide">
          <p>
          <strong>'.$server->hostname.'</strong>
          </p>
          </div>`

Comment: `<div class="map">
          
              '.img(array('src'=>$this->settings->map_image($server->game, $server->currentmap),'id'=>'map_image','width'=>'120px','height'=>'120px')).'
          
             <div class="promo-colt"></div>
             <div class="promo-country">
              '.img(array('src'=>'assets/images/flags/'.$server->country.'.png')).'&nbsp;'.img(array('src'=>'assets/images/games/'.$server->game.'.png')).'&nbsp;
             </div>
          
          </div>`

Comment: `<div class="map-info">
          <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
          
           <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-location-arrow orange"></i> <b>'.$this->lang->line('port').':</b></td>
            <td><p><a href="server_info/'.$server->ip.'/'.$server->port.'">'.$server->ip.'</a></p></td>
           </tr>
           
           <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-map red"></i> <b>Map:</b></td>
            <td>'.$server->currentmap.'</td>
           </tr>
         
          </table>
          </div>
          </div>';`

Comment: `}
        } else {
         echo '<p class="text-center">'.$this->lang->line('zeroserversadded').'</p>';
        }       
       ?>`

Comment: this is to all code  :)

Comment: you should put this code in the question. but seeing all of it, the quotes seem fine.

Comment: what is your jquery version?

Comment: The version is jQuery v1.12.3 but the code works on the servers page but the muting on the main page does not seem to work properly.
On the servers page, the code is different from the index of the website.

Comment: can you please post the html generated for the relevant image in your question? are you sure there is only one element with that id? have you tried using the `on` function to attach the error event, since it's been deprecated? though it should work before vsn 3.

Comment: and have you included jquery? are you getting any js errors?

Comment: this is the html result:

Comment: <img src="http://www.update.gametrack.ro/assets/images/mtamap.png" id="map_image" width="120px" height="120px" alt="" />

Comment: It affects if that id = "map_image" is put in a slider that generates 3 images at once ???

Would it have a connection with it?

Comment: this is the link : http://www.update.gametrack.ro/

Comment: and the problem is in this 4 colons of servers. The image of server "MIX2.BNY.RO @ TS.BNY.RO" not function... This cod is generate 4 same id="map_image" beacause is 4 servers on the page.

Comment: id has to be unique. use  class name instead or add a number to the id.

Comment: Can you help me with an example how to change the code `<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#map_image').error(function() {
                var $img = $(this);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $img.attr('src', '<?=base_url('assets/images/mapnotfound.png');?>' + '?' + Math.random());
                }, 1000);
            });
        }); 
    </script>` if I use class = "map_image" ??

Comment: Just replace `$('#map_image')` with `$('.map_image')`. The dot is used for classes and hash for ids.

Comment: Man, you're brilliant.

Thank you :) it works perfectly !!!

Comment: Great  :) But next time post all the relevant code, will save time :) e.g. the loop you must be using.

Comment: I would need some help with paging the news.
View topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474724/do-you-help-me-pagination-codeigniter

Comment: Sorry man but i new from this website and i dont know to all option to post :)